# Load WKWebView in background/off screen

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Is there a way to load a WKWebView in the background/off-screen so I can hide the loading behind another view?

Comment: Hi James, I had this issue several times as well, may I ask for more detail, why you want to do that off screen? Like creating screen shots or because it looks bad while waiting for it to finish loading? I had different approaches depending on that context.

Comment: @Viktor_DE I don't want the user to see it loading the first time really. Was hoping to just hide it behind another view to mask some of it

Comment: Okay, is it content from web or do you have the files on the device? I'm thinking of an automatic background procedure to create screenshots of those files, as long as they would not change permanently, so the next time you are loading them, you have a screenshot locally to show, the loading speed for me was from 50 to 200 ms, that was just fast enough so the user was not pressing any thing until it finished, and on some files I added a loading indicator on top, so the user sees something but is aware, there is still some loading going on. Might that be good for you?

Comment: @Viktor_DE it's actual content from the web so that wouldn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: Did you manage to solve your question? Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the **WKWebView to the view hierarchy** but its **x is your current width**, so it lays out of the screen but within the rendering hierarchy.

Add **WKNavigationDelegate** to your class and add it to the webView like

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Then implement the following function:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation)
```

This function and some others are called when the webview finished loading the content, **BUT this does not include the 100% finished rendering**. After that there is still some time required for rendering, the time consumption for this depends on the content that was loaded.

There currently is no callback for the 100% finished loading and rendering, so if you know the files, you can calculate or use a fix delay before moving the webView into the visible rect.

OR

If you feel fine with that, you observe private values in the webview and move your webview after those value changes to your preferred state. This looks for example like that:

```
class MyCustomWKWebView: WKWebView {

func setupWebView(link: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: link)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    load(request as URLRequest)
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loading", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    guard let _ = object as? WKWebView else { return }
    guard let keyPath = keyPath else { return }
    guard let change = change else { return }

    switch keyPath {
    case "loading":
        if let val = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Bool {
            //do something!
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}

deinit {
    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loading")
}
}
```